# R update from 3.0 to 3.1 but all packages remain in 3.0

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu, and in my home folder there is `~/R/i686-library/R/3.0` and `/3.1`. My current R version is 3.1, but all of my packages remain in 3.0. Is it possible to just copy paste libraries from 3.0 to 3.1?

Also, what's the best way to update / migrate package when I upgrade R?

Comment: It is my understanding that R packages are compatible only within the same x.y version.  So while you can use a 3.0 package on 3.0.2, you can't use it on 3.1, and should download the updated version of the package.

Comment: Yes, I solved my problem used the link of duplicate above.